# AngularJS: Programmatically adding nested form (ngForm)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

I have a specific problem where I need to add nested form in a form built with angular.

Statically (non-programmatically), I can the do the following:

```
<form>
   ...
   <ng-form>
       <input ng-model="myModel" required>
   </ng-form>
   ...  
</form>
```

And validation error in the nested form invalidates the outer form. Which is exactly what I need.

But I can't seem to do this programmically via a directive. In the template I have the following

```
<div dynamic-nested-form="">

</div>
```

And I have the following:

```
(function () {

angular
    .module('controls')
    .directive('dynamicNestedForm', dynamicNestedForm);

function dynamicNestedForm($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: linkedFunction
    };

    function linkedFunction($scope, element) {

        var nestedForm = angular.element('<ng-form><input ng-model="myModel" required></ng-form>');
        element.append($compile(nestedForm)($scope));
   }
})();
```

The form does get injected in the DOM and it is in invalid state, in Chrome element view, I see

```
<div dynamic-nested-form="" class="ng-scope">

    <ng-form 
        class="ng-pristine ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">      
        <input ng-model="myModel" required="" 
               class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

But outer form does not get invalidated. When the outer form loaded does it not see the inner form?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/nortal/dyngo. Not sure, but I think there was something regarding it. Also don't forget to choose the appropriate branch for documentation.

Comment: Ah,  I think I might have to use the outer form's $addControl() to add the nested form in the directive.  Will try that

Comment: tried looking into `$addControl` but failed to do so. My answer shows how I solved it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Right,
So,
Basically did a little debugging through Angular and it just happens that the nested form could not find the outer form controller. (The outer form controller is needed in `ngModelDirective` in its `preLink`)

The reason it cannot find it is because this `preLink` happens during compile (obviously, it's a `preLink`) and my compile was done before the nested form was attached.

So as a solution, instead of compiling before attaching, I do it after, like

```
var nestedForm  = angular.element('<ng-form><input ng-model="myModel" required></ng-form>');
$compile(element.append(nestedForm ).contents())($scope);
```

Well, I think I am recompiling it.

Anyhoo, this then makes the inner control find the outer form and my problem is solved.